# Scanning File Input Into HashMap in Java

Tags: io, hashmap, java.util.scanner, delimiter

So I am trying to traverse a directory and find all the instances of a file called "rels.txt", and for each instance, I want to go into the file and load up the individual values from the file into a HashMap in Java. Below are the contents of one of the "rels.txt" files I am working with:

**Text File:**

```
rId8,image2
rId13,image5
rId7,image1
rId12,image4
rId17,image8
rId15,image7
rId9,image3
rId14,image6
```

Here is the Java code I have thus far that is supposed to traverse the directory and store each of the values in the HashMap, print out the HashMap, then clear it (so that a new set of values can be stored from another "rels.txt" file within the directory).

**Java Code:**

```
private void traverse(File directory) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        //Get all files in directory
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : files)
        {
            if (file.getName().equals("rels.txt"))
            {
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter(",");
                while (scan.hasNextLine())
                {
                    String id;
                    String image;

                    id = scan.next();
                    image = scan.next();
                    imageMap.put(id, image);
                }
                System.out.println(imageMap);
                imageMap.clear();
            }

            else if (file.isDirectory())
            {
                //It's a directory so (recursively) traverse it
                traverse(file);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the error/output I am getting and I am not quite sure where I am going wrong.

**Error/Output**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at XMLTagParser.traverse(XMLTagParser.java:153)
    at XMLTagParser.traverse(XMLTagParser.java:198)
    at XMLTagParser.traverse(XMLTagParser.java:198)
    at XMLTagParser.<init>(XMLTagParser.java:27)
    at IPDriver.main(IPDriver.java:21)
{image26
rId19=image9
rId31, image15
rId33=image23
rId38, image29
rId21=image11
rId34, image12
rId27=image17
rId30, image28
rId16=image6
rId20, image14
rId32=image22
rId37, image2
rId17=image7
rId25, rId13=image3
rId18, image20
rId35=image25
, image8
rId26=image16
rId39, image24
rId7=image1
rId12, image21
rId14=image4
rId22, image10
rId29=image19
rId24, image13
rId28=image18
rId36, image27
rId15=image5
rId23}
```

With this code, I essentially just want to be able to call the HashMap for another part of my project and when I reference one of the rId values, I can get the corresponding image value. Does anyone have any ideas as to what I may be doing wrong or maybe even a more efficient solution? Thanks in advance.

**Working Java Code Thanks to Friedrik:**

```
private void traverse(File directory) throws FileNotFoundException
        {
            //Get all files in directory
            File[] files = directory.listFiles();
            for (File file : files)
            {
                if (file.getName().equals("rels.txt"))
                {
                    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
                    while (scan.hasNextLine())
                    {
                        String[] line = scan.nextLine().split(",");
                       imageMap.put(line[0], line[1]);

                    }
                    System.out.println(imageMap);
                      imageMap.clear();
                }

                else if (file.isDirectory())
                {
                    //It's a directory so (recursively) traverse it
                    traverse(file);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the delimiter is "," scan.next() reads "image2\nrId13" together. It considers the return as a character, not a delimiter.

Another way to do this, delete the "useDelimiter(",")" of the Scanner and use this loop :

```
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
            while (scan.hasNextLine())
            {
                String[] line = scan.nextLine().split(",");
                imageMap.put(line[0], line[1]);
            }
            System.out.println(imageMap)
```

just make sure that your file doesn't end by a return.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but how do I add an additional argument to the delimiter? (First time working with it, sorry lol)

Comment: maybe in regex "[,][\n]". Not completely sure. I can give you another way to do this if you want.

Comment: yeah sure, im open to any suggestions

Comment: That works great. A lot cleaner than what I was trying to do. Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file is exactly what you said, you can try changing the `hasNextLine` to `hasNext`